# Converting a simple conditional statement constraint into linear equation

Tags: if-statement, optimization, conditional-statements, pulp, linear-optimization

I am using PuLP method to optimize a problem. I have a simple conditional statement as:

> If A = 0, x = 0

> Else if A>0, x = 1

How can I change it into mathematical equation (or a list of equations) if I want to use it as a constraint in optimization using PuLP method?

Comment: Depends heavily on what A exactly is.

Comment: For me A can vary between 0 to 640. I want x to be zero when A is zero. I want x to be 1 when A has any other value.

Answer (score 0):

```
0.001⋅x ≤ A ≤ 640⋅x
x ∈ {0,1}
```

For PuLP split this into two inequality constraints.